# how to parse a table using perl

Tags: perl

```
Name         Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
Student 1      41   51    61 
Student 2      42   52    62 
Student 3      43   53    63  
Student 4      44   54    64 
Student 5      45   55    65
```

I when I give `Name` as input, I need to output the three `Mark` columns. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, what have you tried and what are you stuck on?

Comment: You might consider adding the source of that table. Is it an SQL driven data source? Is it a file?

Comment: Assuming this is file-based, are the fields tab-delimited? Fixed-format? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an array called `@arr`, where each entry is a line, and assuming the number of the student you're looking for is in `$num`, you can use:

```
foreach (@arr) {
    if (/^Student \b$num\b\s+(\d.*\d)/) {
        print "$2\n";
    }
}
```

This iterates over all the entries in the array.  It looks for lines that:

- begin with "Student"
- are followed by the exact number `$num` (the `\b`s around it specify word boundaries, so this can't be part of another number)
- are followed by some whitespace
- have a pattern beginning and ending with a number that is as long as possible.

If so, the pattern beginning and ending with a number is captured and printed.  In this case, it corresponds exactly to Mark1, Mark2 & Mark3.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my %hash = ();
print "Student No:"; #Eg:Student 1
chomp ( my $input = <>);
while (<DATA>) {
    next if /^Name/;
    chomp;
    my ($student, $no, @marks) = split;
    $hash{ "$student " . "$no" } = \@marks;
}
print join " ", @{$hash{ "$input" }};

__DATA__
Name         Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
Student 1      41   51    61
Student 2      42   52    62
Student 3      43   53    63
Student 4      44   54    64
Student 5      45   55    65
```